# Error 1364 field doesn't have a default value when executing a simple insert with join

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I got two simple tables, the field 'ID' is primary key on both. I want to insert the Table 2 field 'Calculated size' into the Table 1 field 'Size', by an inner join on 'ID'.

Table 1:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |

Table 2:

| ID | Calculated_size |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | S |

Expected result for Table 1:

| ID | Size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | S |

Here's my query:

```
insert into Table1 (Calculated_size)
select Size from Table2
inner join Table1
on Table2.ID = Table1.ID;
```

when executed, it gives error 1364: Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value. Why?

I tried turning off STRICT_TRANS_TABLES on SQL mode but it had no effect.

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0.15 and MySQL version 5.7.25-log

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You want `update`, not `insert`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.id = t2iid
    set t1.Calculated_size = t2.size;
```

`insert` inserts new rows into the table -- the unmentioned columns have default values.  `update` updates values in existing rows.